# Objective-C (iOS/Cocoa): expand first letter into day of week

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, switch-statement

I have a coded string "m8" or "w12" and I'd like to expand them into a day object "monday" or "wednesday" and a time object "8:00" or "12:00". The time I can handle but having trouble finding a trivial way (that can be used in a block) to turn an 'm' into 'Monday' in Objective-C (iOS)...

I had initially thought of getting the first letter (always just one letter then 1 or 2 numerals. Thursdays are 'h'. and Sat & Sun not applicable).

```
[codedString substringToIndex:1]  // returns 'm' or 'w', etc...
```

and then using a `switch` statement to set another variable to 'monday' or 'tuesday' and then something similar for the numbers. But, then I remembered you cannot `switch` on an `NSString`. So how does one go about something like this in Objective-C?

Brain hurts switching back & forth between Objective-C & Ruby so I know I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Great ideas (below)! This is what I love about SO...I was looking for one solution, that I couldn't think of, and now I'm aware of at least 3 different approaches... much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a job for a dictionary!

```
NSDictionary *stringToDayMap = @{@"m" : @"Monday", @"t" : @"Tuesday", @"w" : @"Wednesday", @"th" : @"Thursday", @"f" : @"Friday", @"s" : @"Saturday"};
NSString *day = [stringToDayMap objectForKey:[codedString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can switch on any C primitive type. So if it's a single letter then you can do something like:

```
switch([codedString characterAtIndex:0])
{
     case 'h': NSLog(@"This is Thursday");
     ... etc ...
}
```

You'll be switching on a `unichar` but those are explicitly a superset of ASCII so the C character constant 'h' will map correctly on an iOS or OS X target.

Answer (score 2):

You can't switch on a string, but you can on a character.

```
switch([codedString characterAtIndex:0]) {
    case 'm': day = @"Monday";  break;
    case 't': day = @"Tuesday"; break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSRange dayRange = [@"smtwhfa" rangeOfString:[codedString substringToIndex:1]];
NSString* dayString = [dayArray objectAtIndex:dayRange.location];
```

Where dayArray is an NSArray preloaded with @"Sunday", @"Monday", ...

(Dunno what single character is used for Saturday -- substitute as appropriate.)

Comment: You could even get the names of the days of the week from `NSDateFormatter` if you wanted to be really thorough, it'd just be a significant effort involving a suitable date string and dates you know to be on specific days since the simple getter for 'names of the days of the week' will use the user's locale to decide which is the first day of the week (eg, it's Sunday in the US but Monday in the UK per cultural norms).

Comment: @Tommy -- Yeah, there are a bunch of ways to do this.  Probably the dictionary scheme is most straight-forward, if you don't mind too much the cost of the setup.  Or the simple `switch`.  But I like to think of different ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary with the values you want.

```
NSDictionary *daysOfTheWeek = @{@"m": @"Monday", @"t":@"Tuesday"}; // and so on...
```